# How To Install Libpcap With C language Windows 10 - problems with user manual

Tags: c, shared-libraries, mingw, mingw-w64, libpcap

I am currently experiencing a lot of problems with installing libraries on my Computer [ libpcap if we are being specific ] . I am a beginner when it comes to C language and I have never installed any library with it since installing libraries with Python for example requires one-liner. I just spent few hours trying to get libpcap to work with Windows 10 and I still have 0 idea on how it works.

Here is some info on the development environment that I am working in:

- I have MinGW MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.5
- gcc version 8.1.0
- I am running the code by holding ctrl-alt-n with 'Code Runner' in VScode and I have 0 idea on how to work with manifest, makefile, json, building tasks etc. [ idk if these terms are even relevant I just heard about them online lol so pls keep that in mind when explaining ]

I have tried [and failed] :

- manually copy-pasting libcap in mingw lib folder
- the 'manual' that is in the file is really not helping me as it is saying that I need to run './configure' which doesn't work for me [ I mean there is configure file with no extension if that means anything ]
- I have tried adding `#include <E:\\programming\\MinGW\\pcap\\pcap.h>` in the c script that I am developing but its giving me the `fatal error: pcap/pcap.h: No such file or directory #include <pcap/pcap.h> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.`

I have literary run of of things to try and I have spent a lot of time just moving stuff around the files and googling similar problems with no idea of what I am actually doing so you are my only hope. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get libpcap? You should use http://www.winpcap.org/ on Windows. Also your MinGW-w64 is quite old. You can get a newer one via MSYS2's `pacman` or by downloading a standalone version from https://winlibs.com/

Comment: I get the `A newer version of WinPcap is already installed on this machine ...` error. I guess thats because I have WireShark installed but idk how to use their version of libpcap/winpcap as I am quite bad with C. Maybe you can give me some directions?

Comment: You don't need to reinstall winpcap if you already have it. What you need is the library and header files to be able to use it. The source code is here: http://www.winpcap.org/install/bin/WpcapSrc_4_1_3.zip

Comment: CORRECTION: libpcap compiles on Windows now, so just build https://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.10.1.tar.gz

Comment: @BrechtSanders I have that file libpcap-1.10.1, the problem is that I don't really have an idea on what to do with it. I have written what I have tried in the question and I don't really know anything beyond that. Can you please elaborate on how to get it to work in the code or give me any directions [ btw anything is helpful, thanks ]. I have literary 0-day experience with C language except knowing the syntax and writing some basic code [ reversing array, making lists, ... ] so please keep that in mind. I dont really know what headers I need or where to put them [ or what they are lol ].

Comment: You need cmake (https://cmake.org/) to build libpcap.

Comment: I guess this is too complicated for me, I don't really know what I am doing anymore. Before I posted my question, I thought this was gonna be copy-paste type of solution but this goes over my head. Thanks for trying.